# PHP and WordPress: Debugging

Tags: php, debugging, wordpress

I am writing some plugins and themes for WordPress, and I finding it hard to debug because somehow by the time the page has loaded, $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST are all empty. Even with error reporting set on, I am not getting error messages either other than a blank page whenever there is a fatal error. Is there anyway to enable a 'debug mode' for WordPress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pear Debug Wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pear-debug/

**Update 4/08/2015:** The above plugin hasn't been updated in a few years. You can also use the built-in WordPress PHP debugging functions in `wp-config.php` , i.e.:

```
  // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Disable display of errors and warnings 
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress for the complete docs

Comment: As of PHP 7.0 (unsure) that throws almost errors as Exception, it seems that Wordpress sometimes just stop rendering without any error messages. (Of course even though above settings are done. ) Setting `set_exception_handler` https://gist.github.com/kaorukobo/795d43c9a594b021c2d09fffd2935b37 helped this problem.

Comment: Here is a small plugin to control the WP_DEBUG, WP_DEBUG_LOG, WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY, SCRIPT_DEBUG constants with simple toggles and view tidy logs

https://wordpress.org/plugins/issues-tracker/

Answer (score 5):

There's (more than one/) a way to enable "a 'debug mode'" for php in general. And that's installing a debugger extension like e.g. [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/).
You need a client that connects to the debugger and retrieves+displays the information.
[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org) 6.7 has been [released](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) and its php module supports xdebug. It has become a nice [IDE for PHP development](http://www.netbeans.org/features/php/index.html).

Comment: Alas, I am using a hosted webhost, and my PHP development style is to upload directly to the webhost for testing. Thanks though and if I ever do develop on my windows machine I would use this

Answer (score 4):

I know this has long been answered, but if you `define('WP_DEBUG',true);` in your wp-config.php and are still not seeing errors, then add this code right after the define statement:

`if (WP_DEBUG) ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Answer (score 3):

Look at WordPress FirePHP Debugger (spam link removed). It uses FirePHP for debugging wordpress via the web browser.

Main features:

- Automatic detection of FirePHP server library inside php include path or separated directory
- Early loading of the debugger (before WordPress engine starts)
- No modifications to WordPress core or configuration files
- Automatic enabling of WordPress debug mode
- Handles all php fatal errors (no more blank pages and logs parsing)
- Logs WordPress deprecated functions and arguments
- Safe debugging on live site
- SQL queries log
- PHP superglobals and constants
- System information (WordPress and server environment)