# why blank page is open on wordpress link?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I got a copy of the index.php file with a different name (profile.php) and i create a link to profile.php on the index.php file like this:

```
<a href ="<? php bloginfo ('template_url');?> / profile.php"> profile </ a>
```

But when I click on the link opens a completely blank page

Comment: White screen of death is normally a PHP error in the file. Turn on error reporting, here are some debugging options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080679/php-and-wordpress-debugging.  Also looking at your question, what you are doing will cause chaos - copying index.php and putting it into the theme?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

You have unnecessary white spaces in the href attribute which creates the following link:

http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme%20/%20profile.php

Also in your code you have `<? php` but it should be without white space  `<?php`

Change your line to:

```
<a href ="<?php bloginfo ('template_url');?>/profile.php"> profile </ a>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated URL here (you can skip domain part if you want). It is also possible that the link works correctly to your profile.php in your theme but that the profile.php has some error and this is the reason for the blank page.

Comment: if profile.php has not any wordpress function its load well, but if profile.php have wordpress function show blank page

Comment: That's odd. Turn on error reporting by setting define(‘WP_DEBUG’, true); in your wp-config.php .Maybe you will get some useful error information.

Comment: Remove the whitespace between bloginfo & `(`