# Different MySQL Query Result in Localhost and Online Server

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query works on localhost:

```
$clicks = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * 
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}data
    WHERE date BETWEEN ( NOW() - INTERVAL {$args['day']} DAY ) AND NOW()
    {$where}
    ORDER BY {$args['order_by']} {$args['order']}
    LIMIT {$args['data_per_page']} OFFSET {$offset}",

    ARRAY_A
);
```

`$clicks` returns the expected result array.

My localhost uses XAMPP 1.8.3, it uses PHP 5.5.11 and 5.6.16 (based on [this](http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/xampp-version-history-apache-mysql-php/)).

When I test it on online server (I use Hostgator with PHP 5.4.45, and MySQL 5.5.42), `$click` returns empty array.

There is no syntax error caution or any warning so I am confused.

Is it syntax problem? And what is the best practice to debug MySQL query?

Comment: what classes does $wpdb use? It looks like pdo. Are your credentials ok?

Comment: It's a WordPress class to access DB: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb. My credentials are fine. Other queries are executed normally. Only this query that has the problem.

Comment: so your using wordpress and I assume you cannot use the php error reporting options I provided, but could you run wordpress in debug mode or something? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1080679/3664960

Comment: Yes, I've been turning on wp debug since the beginning but I am not seeing any error. I think the query is fine because it's executed normally on localhost, but not online server. Might it be because of different MySQL versions?

Comment: Did you try to run the query on a MySQL client, phpMyAdmin or anything? (On the target server, replacing the values that you need). Also if the query runs ok, try to go on the sourcecode where the query trully runs and change the code to just print the query and exit, may be the parameters are being filled wrong.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I store the date in DB using UTC timezone. But the online server uses CST timezone.

So instead of using `NOW()` I define a new `$date` variable using PHP `time()` and replace the `NOW()` in the query with the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I store the date in DB using UTC timezone. But the online server uses CST timezone. So instead of using `NOW()` I define a new `$date` variable using PHP `time()` and replace the `NOW()` in the query with the variable like this:

```
    $date = date( 'Y-m-d', time() );

    global $wpdb;
    $clicks = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}data
        WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN ( {$date} - INTERVAL {$args['day']} DAY ) AND {$date}
        {$where}
        ORDER BY {$args['order_by']} {$args['order']}
        LIMIT $args['data_per_page'] OFFSET {$offset}",

        ARRAY_A
    );
```

So now the query always return the same results in localhost and online server.